# Installing PyMySQL for Anaconda python

Tags: python, anaconda, pymysql

I have installed two versions of python.

Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1
500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

I'm trying to install PyMySQL for the anaconda python package, the problem is that when i try to install it, it install in the Python 2.7.2.How can i sucesccufly install the library for the anaconda version. I tried using the anaconda command

```
conda install PyMySQ
```

but did not work
and also tried

```
python.exe  C:\Users\jimenez\Downloads\PyMySQL-0.6.2\setup.py install
```

here is what happens

```
C:\Anaconda>python.exe  C:\Users\jimenez\Downloads\PyMySQL-0.6.2\setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing PyMySQL.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to PyMySQL.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to PyMySQL.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found

reading manifest file 'PyMySQL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'PyMySQL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install


creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying PyMySQL.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying PyMySQL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying PyMySQL.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-I
NFO
copying PyMySQL.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist\PyMySQL-0.6.2-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' t
o it
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing PyMySQL-0.6.2-py2.7.egg
Removing c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyMySQL-0.6.2-py2.7.egg
Copying PyMySQL-0.6.2-py2.7.egg to c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages
PyMySQL 0.6.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymysql-0.6.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for PyMySQL==0.6.2
Finished processing dependencies for PyMySQL==0.6.2

C:\Anaconda>python
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1
500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import PyMySQL
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyMySQL
```

in the anaconda directory but it is not working either. What else can i try? In this isnt possible what library can i use in anaconda to access a mysql data server?

Comment: As to why the first step you tried didn't work: It looks like PyMySQL is not supported by Anaconda just yet: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs.html But that doesn't mean that you can't install it on your own so the second step you've tried should work.

Comment: Seems that anaconda is installing the library yet when i call it, it cant find it

Comment: Try: `import sys; sys.path` to ensure the directory to which it was installed is on the path

Comment: i think it is there 
    >>> sys.path
    ['', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\pymysql-0.6.2-py2.7.egg'

Comment: Ah, the import should be lowercase. Please try: `import pymysql`

Comment: same result

ImportError: No module named pymysql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61148/discussion-between-daniel-and-bernie).

Comment: I'm afraid chatting about the subject wouldn't help as I'm fresh out of ideas at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this for a while before realizing that the problem was resolved by calling the python script with python (kind of weird). I'm using Anaconda on Windows.

From python import works fine:

```
(root) c:\python_scripts>python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymysql
>>> quit()
```

Trying to run a script directly from cmd (import fails):

```
(root) c:\python_scripts>script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python_scripts\GRAMR\CTA_monitor.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pymysql
ImportError: No module named pymysql
```

Run with "python" works:

```
(root) c:\python_scripts>python script.py
Script working ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I can install pymysql on my ubuntu system with the command `conda install pymysql`, if there is any file permission problem, run the command `sudo chmod -R 777 youAnacondaPath/anaconda3`.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same issue. and the issue was resolved by conda install pymysql.

Comment: This better as a comment instead of an answer. Or maybe you can enrich it to make it better :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, strangely. Conda claims to have installed it, but import still fails.